# remove border from header html table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have this html bootstrap `table` with `thead` `tbody` 
and this is my code

```
    <table border='1' class='table table-responsive' dir='rtl'>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='6'>
            <span style='margin-right:50px;' class='pull-right'>شركة مصطفى الشرباتي وشركاه</span>
            <span style='margin-left:50px;' class='pull-left'>شركة مصطفى الشرباتي وشركاه</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='6'>
            <span class='pull-right'><small> التاريخ 3-1-2018</small></span>
            <span class='pull-left'><small><div id="print-foot">
  صحفة: 
</div></small></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='3'><u>كشف الذمم العامة بالمجاميع</u></td>
        <td colspan='3'><u>اسم المنطقة {{$city->city_name}} رمز المنطقة {{$city->id}}</u></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='6' style='text-align: center;'>من تاريخ {{$request->fromDate}} الى تاريخ {{$request->toDate}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>اسم العميل</td>
        <td>رقم العميل</td>
        <td>الرصيد المدور</td>
        <td>مدين</td>
        <td>دائن</td>
        <td>الرصيد</td> 
    </tr>   
</thead>
<tbody>
    @php $total = 0;$first_total = 0; $debt_total= 0; $total_re =0 ;@endphp
    @foreach($customers as $customer)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$customer->customer_name}}</td>
            <td>{{$customer->id}}</td>
            <td>
                {{round($customer->getVouchers->where('voucher_date','<',$request->fromDate)->sum('voucher_amount'),3)}}
                @php $first_total+=  $customer->getVouchers->where('voucher_date','<',$request->fromDate)->sum('voucher_amount')@endphp
            </td>
            <td>
                {{
                    round($customer->getVouchers()->
                    where('voucher_amount','>',0)->
                    whereBetween('voucher_date',[$request->fromDate,$request->toDate])->
                    sum('voucher_amount'),3)
                }}
                @php $debt_total += $customer->getVouchers()->
                    where('voucher_amount','>',0)->
                    whereBetween('voucher_date',[$request->fromDate,$request->toDate])->
                    sum('voucher_amount') @endphp
            </td>
            <td>
                {{
                    round($customer->getVouchers()->
                    where('voucher_amount','<',0)->
                    whereBetween('voucher_date',[$request->fromDate,$request->toDate])->
                    sum('voucher_amount'),3) * -1
                }}
                @php $total_re += $customer->getVouchers()->
                    where('voucher_amount','<',0)->
                    whereBetween('voucher_date',[$request->fromDate,$request->toDate])->
                    sum('voucher_amount') @endphp
            </td>
            <td>
                @if($customer->getVouchers->where('voucher_date','<=',$request->toDate)->sum('voucher_amount') > 0)
                    {{round($customer->getVouchers->where('voucher_date','<=',$request->toDate)->sum('voucher_amount'),3)}} م
                    @php $total+= round($customer->getVouchers->where('voucher_date','<=',$request->toDate)->sum('voucher_amount'),3) @endphp
                @elseif($customer->getVouchers->where('voucher_date','<=',$request->toDate)->sum('voucher_amount') < 0)
                    {{round($customer->getVouchers->where('voucher_date','<=',$request->toDate)->sum('voucher_amount'),3) * -1}} د
                    @php $total+= round($customer->getVouchers->where('voucher_date','<=',$request->toDate)->sum('voucher_amount'),3) @endphp
                @elseif($customer->getVouchers->where('voucher_date','<=',$request->toDate)->sum('voucher_amount') == 0)
                    0 د
                @endif
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2'>المجموع</td>
        <td>{{round($first_total,3)}} م</td>
        <td>{{round($debt_total,3)}} م</td>
        <td>{{round($total_re,3) * -1}} د</td>
        <td>
            @if($total > 0)
                {{round($total,3)}} م
            @else
                {{round($total,3) * - 1}} د
            @endif
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

now this is the image i gat im print preview
[image]

i need to remove the `thead` border to let the `table` looks like this 
[image]

to remove the border from `thead` and let the border just in the `tbody` thanks a lot

Comment: So, just do so. Put your CSS into a proper stylesheet and adjust the borders with media queries

Comment: i have no css code its clean page could you wright the code to me please

Comment: You use inline styles which should not be done anywhere (except if you know exactly what you do), and these can simply be converted to CSS. And no, I won't write your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is something that will work ... hope it helps.

```
<title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style>
        table {border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; direction: rtl;}
        thead {border: 1px solid white;}
        thead th {border: 1px solid black;}
        thead td {border: 1px solid white;}
        tbody td {border: 1px solid black; width: 15%;}
        .r-padded {padding: 10px 0;}
        .l-padded {padding: 10px 0; text-align: left;}
        .c-padded {padding: 15px 0; text-align: center; border-bottom: 1px solid black;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table class='table table-responsive'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='3' class='r-padded'>شركة مصطفى الشرباتي وشركاه </td>
        <td colspan='3' class="l-padded">شركة مصطفى الشرباتي وشركاه </td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='3' class="r-padded"><small> التاريخ 3-1-2018</small></td>
        <td colspan='3' class="l-padded"><small><div id="print-foot"> صحفة: </div></small></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='3' class="r-padded"><u>كشف الذمم العامة بالمجاميع</u></td>
        <td colspan='3' class="l-padded"><u>اسم المنطقة city_name رمز المنطقة id</u></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='6' class="c-padded">من تاريخ fromDate الى تاريخ toDate</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>اسم العميل</th>
        <th>رقم العميل</th>
        <th>الرصيد المدور</th>
        <th>مدين</th>
        <th>دائن</th>
        <th>الرصيد</th> 
    </tr>   
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <!-- table code continues -->
```

Answer (score 2):

```
tbody tr td {
border: 1px solid #000;
}
table {
border-spacing: 0px;
}
```

This should do.
Remove the border='1' from the top line.